# Using Datavisualization.swc in my Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder, advanceddatagrid

I have upgraded my Flex Builder compiler to SDK 3.2 from SDK 3.0 and as a result unable to use AdvanceDataGrid in my application anymore. I think I need to download the 'datavisualization_SDK3.2.zip’ and add it to my build path to be able to use it again. Can anyone please provide me the link where I can download it ? Or any other suggestion in this regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Ashine.

Answer (score 1):

I got this SWC inside latest Flash Builder setup @{myPath}\sdks\3.5.0\frameworks\libs in the form of 'datavisualization.swc'.

Thanks again.